# Piskei HaRosh - Standalone Edition

Tags: talmud-gemara

Does anyone know of a standalone edition of Piskei HaRosh?

I know it's found in the back of the Gemara, but a standalone edition would be helpful for my purposes.

Comment: I have only seen it on Megillah - https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/hlkvt-rb-alps-psqi-hra-w-tvsvpvt-hra-w-el-mskt-mgilh.html

Comment: I imagine this question was inspired by the recent SeforimChatter episode on the Rosh. https://seforimchatter.com/2023/05/07/with-prof-ephraim-kanarfogel-discussing-the-rosh-rabeinu-asher-b-yechiel-1250-1327/

Comment: Seforim Chatter episode was excellent and definitely made me think about this

Comment: Never seen it, and don't think there's a market for it either.

Comment: You might be able to make one using sefaria.  https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Bavli/Rishonim%20on%20Talmud/Rosh

Answer (score 1):

I know of modern standalone editions of Piskei HaRosh for [Megilla](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990017849370205171/NLI) and [Shevuot](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990010884980205171/NLI). Some older editions I'm aware of:

- [Berachot, Halachot Ketanot, Ḥullin, Bechorot, Nidda, Mikvaot](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/37781)
- [Pesachim](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990018368190205171/NLI)
- [Makkot](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990018367340205171/NLI)

Comment: Thank you. Any idea where to purchase the new ones?